# Using url_helpers in a coffeescript file with a base url in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

I am trying to use Rails url_helpers inside of coffescript files. I append the .erb extension to the filename (profile.js.coffee.erb) and use ERB to access the helpers like so:

```
jQuery ->
  window.Intl.Models.Profile = Backbone.Model.extend
    url: '<%= Intl::Application.routes.url_helpers.profile_path %>'
```

This works great in development and it will return `/profile`. In production, I am using a URL root of `/intl` so I tell the asset pre-compiler to consider this in deploy.rb

```
set :asset_env, "#{asset_env} RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT='/intl'"
```

However, this doesn't seem to affect the url_helpers because it will still return `/profile` instead of `/intl/profile`

I tried setting ENV["RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT"] in production.rb and development.rb respectively and that didn't work either.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set this at the Rack level. If you are using Passenger, you can set the `RackBaseURI` directive.

Comment: The problem with doing this with Rack and Passenger is that `rake assets:precompile` knows nothing of the web server configuration... it is running as a Rake task. RackBaseURI is working just fine, precompiling assets are not

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
As a partial solution I use

```
set :asset_env, "#{asset_env} RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=/csc"
```

in deploy.rb for Capistrano deploymment. This works fine for all other aspects of the asset precompilation except this single aspect (.coffee.erb) wich seems completely unaffected by that setting.